# Symbolizing Certain Attributes in a Polygon and the Excluding One in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have a map full of 78,000+ parcels. I want to fill in the color of all parcels owned by the US Government. One problem is they are named several different ways in my data ("United States of America", "US Forest Service", "United States Forest Service", etc.). So I built a formula that looks like this:

```
"ACCT_NAME" = 'UNITED STATES FOREST SERVICE' OR  "ACCT_NAME" = 'U S NATIONAL FOREST' OR "ACCT_NAME" = 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA'
```

This works and narrows down all the entries to 66.

Now out of 66 government owned properties, I have one of the parcels that is owned by "UNITED STATES FOREST SERVICE" that I don't want to display. So I tried to eliminate this single parcel by another attribute, so I added the following:

```
"ACCT_NAME" = 'UNITED STATES FOREST SERVICE' OR  "ACCT_NAME" = 'U S NATIONAL FOREST' OR "ACCT_NAME" = 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA' OR "PIN" != '7626736067'
```

This doesn't work. I tried adding "IS NOT" "<>" and "!=" as the operators, but none seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `OR` is a dangerous logical operator. You should always use parenthesis to explicitly group your logic.  Of course, if you use the `IN` operator, your query is easier to write, and less vulnerable -- `"ACCT_NAME" in ('UNITED STATES FOREST SERVICE', 'U S NATIONAL FOREST' ,'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA')`

Answer (score 1):

As Vince pointed out, the issue is with the `or`.

The current statements says "select every polygon whose name is X or Y or that is not ID Z", so basically the whole layer will be selected.

You would need two distinct class of criteria to be combined (`and`):  "select every polygon whose (name is X or Y) AND (that is not ID Z)" --> both must be true, i.e the proper name and not the specific ID.